# Iterating through an Array of Arrays returns a different value than expected

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

```
1.9.3-p286 :039 > (0...x.right.first.chem_species.size).each do |atom|
1.9.3-p286 :040 >     puts x.right.first.chem_species[atom]
1.9.3-p286 :041?>   end
H
2
O
1
 => 0...2 
1.9.3-p286 :042 > x.right.first.chem_species[0]
 => ["H", 2] 
1.9.3-p286 :043 >
```

Why doesn't the puts output 
`["H",2]` and then `["O",1]`. (as the second method returns). This doesn't seem right

Comment: What is the class for `chem_species` - is it a Hash?

Comment: x.right.first.chem_species.class -> Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts):

> **puts(obj, ...) → nil**
>
> Equivalent to
>
> ```
> $stdout.puts(obj, ...)
> ```

And for [`IO.puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> **puts(obj, ...) → nil**
>
> [...] If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

So `puts [1,2]` prints `1` and `2` separated by newlines.

When you do this:

```
1.9.3-p286 :042 > x.right.first.chem_species[0]
 => ["H", 2]
```

you're letting `irb` display the Array and `irb` will use `inspect` to produce the output and `['H', 2].inspect` is `["H", 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

```
(0...x.right.first.chem_species.size).each do |atom|
  puts x.right.first.chem_species[atom]
end
```

Can be more clearly written as:

```
x.right.first.chem_species.each do |atom|
  puts atom
end
```

Comment: And more briefly: `x.right.first.chem_species.each &method(:puts)` :-)